# Spring Integration with ftp to perform operation using file

Tags: spring-integration

I want to read file from ftp and store it locally and after storing it locally i want to process that file in java code. After processing the file successfully i want to move it to another directory. How to do it efficiently with using spring integration with ftp

```
public class FtpFileHandler {

public File ftpFileUserHandler(@Header("timestamp")  String timestamp,  File file){
    try {
        String filename = file.getName();
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);                            

        }
        return file;
    } catch ( IOException | org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        Utility.exceptionLogger(e);
        return file;
    }
}
```

}

```
<bean id="ftpFileHandlerService" class="com.aaa.clear.integration.service.impl.FtpFileHandler" />

<!--  HR Integration Start -->
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"                                        
                                 session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                                 charset="UTF-8"                                     
                                 auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                 delete-remote-files="true"    
                                 filename-regex=".*\.(txt)$"                        
                                 remote-directory="/FTP Test"
                                 remote-file-separator="/"
                                 preserve-timestamp="true"              
                                 temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
                                 local-directory="#{systemProperties['aaa']}/clear/integration/download/user">
                                <int:poller fixed-rate="180000" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator id="" input-channel="ftpInbound" output-channel="ftpOutbound" ref="ftpFileHandlerService" method="ftpFileUserHandler" >      
</int:service-activator>    

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound" session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" auto-create-directory="true"
        remote-directory="/FTP Test/processed/user"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/)
- Check out [the samples here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more)
- Come back if you have a specific question

Comment: hi gary, i have added my code above i am getting file contents but i need filename too. and after return success i need the file to rename or move to another folder on remote folder

Comment: The `<file-to-bytes-transformer/>` puts the file and filename in headers `file_originalFile` and `file_name` respectively. You can make these available to your service using `@Header` annotations on parameters, or use them in a downstream service activator: `<service-activator ... expression="headers[file_originalFile].renameTo('/foo/' + headers['name'])" />`. To move it to a different remote folder, use an ftp outbound gateway (`mv` command). See the FTP Support section in the documentation.

Comment: hi gary, after putting multiple files on ftp folder it download all files but not all are send to service-activator. how can i achieve it ? All files are moving to processed directory but first i want to process through service-activator.

Comment: I think you must be mistaken - you need to show your current configuration, but it's extremely unlikely (impossible) that the files can be "moved" after download unless they are processed. Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flow.

Comment: hi gary, i have updated the latest code above. When more than one file are transferred from ftp to local directory only one file is send to FtpFileFactory. how can i get all files in FtpFileFactory ?

Comment: As I said; you need to look at DEBUG logs. All transferred files will be sent as messages. However, files with the same name will only be processed once; read the documentation about file filters.

Comment: Hi Gary, i have updated the code above. I am putting multiple files on ftp and getting the same files in local folder. But only one file is sent to  handler( ftpFileUserHandler) method. all file names are different in this case.

Comment: Once again; use DEBUG logging to debug this; if you can't work it out yourself, post the log somewhere like pastebin or a github gist.